# ViewPager and DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i have a FragmentActivity that has two fragments that i control through a viewpager.  i want to add a DrawerLayout to this FragmentActivity to have two more Fragments.

the XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titleTaskList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#fff"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the FragmentActivity:

in OnCreate:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.titleTaskList);
 mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);  //TabsPagerAdapter implements FragmentPagerAdapter and contains two fragments (2 tabs)



 menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Raspberry Pi","WordPress","Videos","Contact Us"};
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
        dList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
        dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

                dLayout.closeDrawers();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
                Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
                detail.setArguments(args);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
            }
        });
```

the DetailFragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView text;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_detail_fragment, container, false);
        String menu = getArguments().getString("Menu");
        text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);

        text.setText(menu);
        if(menu.equals("Home"))
        {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return null;
        }
        return view;
    }


}
```

i cant display the whole code because its large (but upon your request i will display any related code).
The tabs are displaying and i have no problem with the view pager. but when selecting an item from the DrawerLayout, the layout changes its color and a textview is being displayed as it should but if i click on the display, ill be clicking on the view of the previous tab fragment (view of the previous fragment is invisible but clicking on the view after an item from the DrawerLayout is clicked, leads to clicking on the list or whatever is in the previous fragment.) So my question is if i was not clear, how can i move on to a selected fragment when an item from the drawerLayout is clicked, same as done with a viewpager

Comment: https://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ViewPager-ActionBarCompat

Comment: thank you for the link its really useful and easy to understand, but i can't do as the example states because i should then change major parts in my code because i am using FragmentActivity.